# APN fails for Apple Profile Manager

Tags: ios, apple

We have a new Mac on which we configured profile manager from scratch. Were trying to use it as an MDM to push profile settings over the WAN. I have obtained an APN certificate and the server is using a publicly accessible hostname. I can start the enrollment process (https://URLToMacSrvr/mydevices), but APN doesnt seem to work. The log shows ***"peer(187) received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID"***. In profile manager, all active tasks remain Pending. What i am missing?

> Jan 28 20:45:06 iosmbmsrvr mdmclient[187]: ApplePushService:  asked for publicToken, got <6065c235 8556a4f4 188ee55f 0e5bca8d b11a5bfa 4b635675 06de7561 44a42a9b> ,
>   Jan 28 20:45:06 --- last message repeated 1 time --- 
>   Jan 28 20:45:06 iosmbmsrvr apsd[87]: successful entitlement check 'com.apple.private.push-to-wake' for mdmclient[187] 
>   Jan 28 20:45:44 iosmbmsrvr apsd[87]: peer(187) received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID 
>   Jan 28 20:47:37 iosmbmsrvr apsd[87]: : Preferences may have changed, checking for any relevant changes 
>   Jan 28 20:47:38 --- last message repeated 4 times --- 
>   Jan 28 20:47:38 iosmbmsrvr apsd[87]: : Change in users with uid new = (501), logged out = () 
>   Jan 28 20:47:38 iosmbmsrvr apsd[87]: : Starting login of uid 501 
>   Jan 28 20:47:38 iosmbmsrvr apsd[87]: : Changing status for uid 501 from logged out to logged in 
>   Jan 28 20:47:38 iosmbmsrvr apsd[87]: : Logging user with uid 501 into environment development 
>   Jan 28 20:47:38 iosmbmsrvr apsd[87]: : Will wait patiently for user 501 before recreating the courier state 
>   Jan 28 20:47:38 iosmbmsrvr apsd[87]: : Will wait patiently for user 501 darkWakeEnabled before recreating the courier state 
>   Jan 28 20:47:38 iosmbmsrvr apsd[87]: : Logging user with uid 501 into environment production 
>   Jan 28 20:47:38 iosmbmsrvr apsd[87]: : Will wait patiently for user 501 before recreating the courier state 
>   Jan 28 20:47:38 iosmbmsrvr apsd[87]: : Will wait patiently for user 501 darkWakeEnabled before recreating the courier state 
>   Jan 28 20:47:38 iosmbmsrvr apsd[87]: Determining whether uid 501 is bootstrapped 
>   Jan 28 20:47:38 iosmbmsrvr apsd[87]: Unable to bootstrap_look_up port 'com.apple.apsctl.login' for uid 501: Unknown service name (1102) 
>   Jan 28 20:47:38 iosmbmsrvr apsd[87]: : Set active push connection state to YES 
>   Jan 28 20:47:38 iosmbmsrvr apsd[87]: peer(221) received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID